# Magneto 2.4 - Remove Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2

Tags: magento2, fonts, blank-theme, icons-blank-theme

In our Magento 2.4 we created our own theme based on the Luma theme.
Now we found out that every page loads the Blank Theme Icons font. `/fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2`

How can we remove this?

We already tried the following in `/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

But still the file is loaded. What are we missing here?

Comment: hi, were you able to resolve this issue? I have a similar issue of removing loading of Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2

Comment: @Shailesh Thanks! Sadly we still face this issue, we were not able to solve this issue yet. Keep me updated if you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this solved.

@font-face for the icons are defined in `lib/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less`
You can remove the font icons if you remove line 10 - 43 completely or simply by adding a `not` on line 17.

See not added in caps.

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name,
    @font-path,
    @font-format: false,
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: auto
) when NOT (@font-format = false) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: @family-name;
        src: url('@{font-path}.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{font-path}.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: @font-weight;
        font-style: @font-style;
        font-display: @font-display;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly that also effect the fonts in the backend. So any idea how to only exclude the Blank Theme Icons?

Comment: @JGeer
I have not tested this, but perhaps adding `_typography.less` to your admin theme and keeping the @font-face for icon font there?
`/app/design/adminhtml/<your_vendor>/<your_theme>/web/css/source/_typography.less`

Comment: Well that can be a solution. Or will it also work to leave the default Magento code and copy the _typography.less file into our frontend theme and then remove the @font-face by adding the not part?